# Convert link to anchor only if domain exists

Tags: php, hyperlink, verification

I have a link detection in my site which turns links input by users to anchors but I want to limit conversion of crap links that don't exist and I have built the following

```
public function tLink($s){
    $domain = preg_replace('/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '\4', $s);
    getmxrr($domain,$result);
    if(!empty($result)){
        return preg_replace('/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0" title="\0">\4</a>', $s);
    }
    return $s;
}
```

But this makes my pages load really slow, takes anywhere from 2 to 5 seconds to load. ( they used to load instantly ). Is there a better method I can use?

Comment: Without seeing getmxrr it's kinda hard to tell. The problem could be there, or did you use to use getmxrr when the page loaded instantly?

Comment: @Styphon http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php

Comment: Ah, never seen that before :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the output of `getmxrr` to ensure your not doing the same operation for already validated domains.

assuming you have configured and install memcache. You can replace your lookup with this function

```
function domain_found($domain) { 
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('localhost', 11211);
$var = $memcache_obj->get($domain);
if ($var == "found") return true;
if ($var == "notfound") return false;

    getmxrr($domain,$result); 
    if (empty($result)) {
      $memcache_obj->put($domain, 'notfound');
      return false;
    } else {
      $memcache_obj->put($domain, 'found');
      return true;
    }   
}
```

You can ofcourse work this inside a class if you like, and optimize other value elements. This serves as a proof of concept code.

Comment: How do you suggest I should go about caching this stuff :?